# Best way to handle a model relationship status/state when unit testing in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-6

I have the following unit test in Laravel 6.x, using SQLite:

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Entry;
use App\EntryStatus;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Entry::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'caption' => $faker->sentence(10),
        'entry_status_id' => EntryStatus::where('name', 'pending')->first()->id,
    ];
});

$factory->state(Entry::class, 'awaiting_payment', [
    'entry_status' => EntryStatus::where('name', 'awaiting_payment')->first()->id,
]);
```

I have a test error of 'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object', which is for the following line:

```
'entry_status' => EntryStatus::where('name', 'awaiting_payment')->first()->id,
```

I have a few ideas on how to fix this error, but I'm wondering what the best practice here would be in terms of unit testing and 'The Laravel way'.

The way I have thought about this, I have an EntryStatus table which has static statues 'pending' => 0, 'awaiting_payment' => 1, 'paid' => 2 etc. And I create a relationship within my App\Entry model > App\EntryStatus. Ideas are as follows:

1. The original plan; for the unit tests, I need to seed the static EntryStatus table each time for each test. Looking at the docs, I would use something like setUp() > $this->artisan('db:seed'). But this feels like it would really slow the tests. Unless there is a way to seed the DB once before all tests are started.
2. Try and create a factory which creates static data ('pending' => 0, 'awaiting_payment' => 1) but I'd manually need to update the database seed and the factory each time to match which seems clunky.
3. Within the Laravel docs testing documents they have this example; $factory->state(App\User::class, 'delinquent', ['account_status' => 'delinquent',]). This makes me think I could just remove the relationship table EntryStatus completely and just use a string column in the Entry to represent the state. I think this would be the best solution, but I'm worried that there is a reason we use ids as statuses as I'd imagine that they are quicker in search queries. But if not, my statues will be fixed, and this seems like the most eloquent solution.

Another option would be to store the statues as integers anyway, keeping a note of what status is what integer, but again this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Based on the error you clearly don't have a entry_status with the name awaiting_payment. Wouldn't it help just to seed it? Or am i missing a point?

Comment: Maybe it’s that simple, how would you suggest I seed it unit testing using SQLite? Without slowing the tests down?

Comment: i guess you are already migrating the database on each execution? i had big projects with all weird shenanigans going on and sqlite is blazing fast :) seems like the best way to write code that is maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record is not created yet and its not a good idea to assign static relationships this way in factories.

You can use a factory `create` instead then assign the relationship inside the test case.

For example:

`Entry` factory

```
$factory->define(Entry::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory(User)->create()->id,
        'caption' => $faker->sentence(10),
        'entry_status_id' => factory(EntryStatus)->create()->id,
    ];
});
```

`EntryStatus` factory

```
$factory->define(EntryStatus::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->word,
        'entry_status' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 2) //Its better start from 1 though
    ];
});
```

`User` factory

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->word
    ];
});
```

In your test case start linking things together (if you need to).

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function exampleTestCase()
{
    $enteryStatus = factory(EntryStatus::class)->create(['entry_status' => 1]);

    //create 6 entries
    $entry = factory(Entry::class, 6)->create(['entry_status_id' => $enteryStatus->id]);

    //TODO: assert something
}
```

You can check `afterCreatingState`

```
$factory
    ->state(EntryStatus::class, 'awaiting_payment', ['name' => 'awaiting_payment'])
    ->afterCreatingState(EntryStatus::class, 'awaiting_payment', function ($entryStatus, $faker) {
        factory(Entry::class)->create([
            'entry_status_id' => $entryStatus->id,
        ]);
    });
```